# Are derived class and deriving class interchangeable terms?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

Consider the following statement that I quoted from [Inheritance and Derived Classes (C# vs Java)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228387%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> You can extend the functionality of an existing class by creating a
>   new class that derives from the existing class. The derived class
>   inherits the properties of the base class, and you can add or override
>   methods and properties as required.

Now, let's compare with the following that I quoted from a book.

> Abstract classes are similar to interfaces in many ways. They can both
>   define member signatures that deriving classes must implement, and
>   neither one of them can be instantiated.

Shortly speaking, are derived class and deriving class interchangeable terms?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming not English, and so belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network such as StackOverflow proper, Programmer.SE, or any number of other unEnglish sites.

Comment: The derived class is a particular class that's derived from its base class. Deriving classes are all such classes. So B derives from A. C derives from A. A's deriving classes are B & C.

Comment: One might as well ask whether the ***driving*** snow is as white as the ***driven*** snow.

Comment: In programming circles they can be used interchangeably but there is a grammatical difference between the two (the subjects and the objects of the deriving act are different).

Comment: You can ask on ELL for the general English aspect and  programmerSE for the domain-specific meaning. May be off-topic on ELU.

Comment: Can ask on ELL for the general English aspect and programmerSE for the domain-specific meaning. May be off-topic on ELU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All uses relate to the word *derive* in different ways, and are more or less equivalent but for different reasons, which relates to English rather than programming. Note that there is actually a third used in your examples, *derives*.

Now, in non-technical English, *derive* means either to obtain something from some source, or to originate from a source (along with some other meanings not relevant here), for example here where we are talking about English we'd often talk about how one word or sense of a word derived from another.

In the context of object oriented programming, this is used specifically about inheritance, but it is a clear extension of the existing non-technical sense; it is jargon of specificality rather than invented jargon.

The different forms in your example, simply relate to how the class is treated by the sentence:

```
You can derive a new class.
```

Here *derive* is used as a verb describing what the programmer can do.

```
The second class is derived from the first.
```

Here we've the same verb in the past tense.

```
The derived class inherits members from the base class.
```

Here we're using the preterite (past tense) form of the verb to describe the class (that is, as an adjective) much as we would talk of "shorn hair", "stained clothes", "cooked meat" etc.

```
The class derives from its base.
```

Here we are using the verb slightly differently in that we are making the class the subject of the sentence rather than the object - were before we talked of the class with the programmer as the subject, here the class itself is.

```
The deriving class inherits members from the base class.
```

This conveys exactly the same information as the earlier example sentence, but again does so with the class as the subject of the verb - rather than use the preterite to serve an adjectival role as with "cooked meat" we use the gerund to serve an adjectival role in describing something the class has done like we could "the speeding car".

Grammatically there is a difference because not all verbs can be used so similarly of something as both a subject and an object, but *derive* has senses that cover both. Informationally there's no difference because these senses both exist.

Answer (score 0):

derived : you have already created a new class

deriving : you are wondering if creating a new class is what you really need

Comment: No, because the class is the subject of the use of *deriving* in the example above, and it is not likely that it is wondering anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think that "derived" refers to something that has already been created. Deriving is more general and refers, also, to all classes that potentially can be derived.